# How to assign a default value to DetailsView in insert mode?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I tried to write a code to assign a value when I change the **DetailsView** to insert mode. for example, I need to assign an ID in a field:
 
1- I converted the field to (**edit template**).
 
2- I give it a new id. 
 
3- I used this code in a **Button_Click** as below :

```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert)
    Dim txt As TextBox
    If DetailsView1.CurrentMode = DetailsViewMode.Insert Then
        txtBox = DirectCast(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
        txtBox .Text = ViewState("932")
    End If
End Sub
```

but when I clicked the button it gives me this error.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

any help please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: is there any solution?